# Show that $\,f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, for $x \in [0,1]$, is of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, bounded-variation

Let $\{a_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, be such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert < \infty$. Define 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \quad \text{for } x \in [0,1]$$
Prove that $f$ is of bounded variation.

**Attempt:**

Let $P = \{ x_0, \ldots , x_n \}$ be any partition of $[0,1]$. Then
$$ 
\sum_{i=1}^n \left| \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x_i^j - \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x_{i-1}^j \right| = \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j [ x_i^j - x_{i-1}^j ] \right|.
$$
Since 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert < \infty$ and $x_i \in [0,1]$ $\forall i$,
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left| a_j [ x_i^j - x_{i-1}^j ] \right| 
\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert < \infty.
$$
Hence, $f(x)$ is of bounded variation since the elements of the sum are finite the index of the outer sum is also finite.

Is this a valid approach? What other ways are there to prove this?

Comment: Your expression $\sum_{i=1}^n \left| a_j [ x_i^j - x_{i-1}^j ] \right|$ doesn't make any sense.  What does $j$ mean when it isn't the index of a summation?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks.  It's not enough to just bound each $i$ separately.  This gives an upper bound of $n \sum_{j=0}^\infty |a_j|$ for the variation, and that's unbounded (since $n$ can be arbitrarily large).

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks, that makes sense. Although, how else would you tackle this? This is the only definition of bounded variation that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$
0=x_0<\cdots<x_n=1,
$$
then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert\, f(x_{k})-f(x_{k-1})\rvert=\sum_{k=1}^n\left|\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx_k^j-\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx_{k-1}^j\right|
\le\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^\infty\left| a_j\right|(x_{k}^j-x_{k-1}^j) \\ = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left| a_j\right|\sum_{k=1}^n(x_{k}^j-x_{k-1}^j)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\lvert a_j\rvert<\infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks for this. Is this essentially the same as my approach? I see in the comments to my question that it apparently is not enough to bound each $i$ separately because $i$ can be infinitely large.

Comment: @mathjacks This solution uses the stronger fact that $\sum_{k=1}^n (x^j_k - x^j_{k-1}) = 1$. You only used $|x^j_k - x^j_{k-1}| \le 1$.  Yiorgos's bound is for the total variation independent of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $g(x) = \sum_{a_{k}>=0}a_{k}*x^{k}$ and $h(x) = \sum_{a_k < 0} |a_{k}|*x^{k}$
Then both g(x) and h(x) are increasing so they are of finite variance.
Clearly f = g - h so it must be of finite variance as well (triangle inequality).